# Angularjs: custom directive scope is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a directive that process data from attribute value. the directive is only going to be used as an attribute on an element. So for now i just want to run a function whenever it is called

The directive call is like this:

```
<div rest="accounts">
    {{testing}}
</div>
```

Directive definition goes like this:

```
app.directive("rest", [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            rest: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            console.log(scope);
        }
    };
}])
```

everytime i use the directive, the log shows the property `rest` as `undefined`.. accounts is just a string because i want to test the directive first, but yet i don't know why it is always undefined, even with using `$watch` like this:

```
app.directive("rest", [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            rest: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch('rest', function(data){
                console.log(data); //Still undefined
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: `account` must be undefined before giving it to the directive. How is it initialized?

Comment: is accounts attached to parent controller scope? $scope.accounts?

Comment: @RocoCTZ `accounts` is just a string. it is not attached to any scope

Comment: That's the problem. It should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are using to pass values is passing a variable reference rather than a string value.

With `rest="accounts"` in the HTML, `=` in scope implies two way binding, where the inner property `scope.rest` is bound to the outer property `$scope.accounts`.

If you *always* intend to pass a string, you should use `@` in the scope property instead.  This implies a one way binding between `rest` and the string value.

You can also use the directive as written without defining `$scope.accounts` by supplying your value as a string literal, i.e. `rest="'accounts'"`.  This form should be used sparingly, however, due to the cumbersome nature of the nested quotes.